# How to create a Custom form for SharePoint online per view

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, sharepoint-list, powerapp

I have a SharePoint List with 90 Different Columns and 20 different Views.
I know it is possible to have different Form for edit, view and save for a list.
My question is how to create a form screen per Sharepoint ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the list form using InfoPath.

Open the list form in InfoPath, click "New View" in the PAGE DESIGN tab, give a view name and it will open a new form to customize.

[image]

[image]